# Can we look just at the other features when we have a missing vaue?

Tags: missing-data

For my classification task i have 3 features a,b,c.
Feature c is missing for some datas.
I can have already a good score for my classifier training with the two other features a,b and even better if I don't look at the missing data and I train with a,b,c.

Is it possible to train my classifier with features a,b,c on all the data which don't have missing values, and in my prediction phase, if the feature c is missing, to predict the class like if I had train my classifier with a and b?

Comment: A tedious way could be to train two different classifiers. One using `a`, `b`, and `c` as features by removing the instances that don't have values for `c`, and the other classifier using `a` and  `b` only on the entire data. Then during the prediction phase, depending on whether the data has feature `c` missing or not, choose the appropriate classifier.

Comment: Please clarify the question: are you suggesting training two distinct classifiers (as addressed in the comment by @tomar__) or are you asking if your classification algorithm would be robust enough to generalize well to cases (not seen in training) where c is missing (assuming you can represent that). In the latter case, please provide information about your classification algorithm.

Comment: I would like to do why @tomar__ said, but is it possible to do it with just one classifier: Train on a,b,c and if in my test phase, c is missing, I rely just on feature a,b like If I had an other classifier train on a,b.

Answer (score 1):

Try a few options and pick the best.

1. Fill in the mean/median from known $c$'s in the $a,b,c$ model
2. Create a linear regression model to predict $c$ from $a,b$, fill the estimate $c$ from this model in the $a,b,c$ model
3. Train both models and use the applicable one

Personally, I think 2. will work best in most cases, but 1. can already be sufficient when $c$ is not correlated to $a$ or $b$.

Comment: I would say 3. is the way to go if there is no correlation as the c median can induce an error. It's better to have no data than bad data.

Comment: The point of invalid data = bad data must indeed be considered, and only trying will show if there is a positive effect, a negative effect, or no effect at all.